# Would the flesh of a giant slug, which grows to the size of an adult micro pig, be able to be cut and prepared as a steak?

Tags: food

So basically I'm mapping out the kinds of foods a people would prepare whose main source of protein comes from giant slugs and the ranches that raise them and am going through the motions of how slug meat would actually perform as a cooking ingredient. Whether or not it will remain cohesive when heat is applied, what its texture will be after it's been cooked, if it would be tough and chewy if overcooked like calamare, and so on.

But my biggest quandary is how it would hold up and perform as various cuts of meat, most importantly as a steak-like slab of flesh, since I think a boneless creature like a slug would be able to provide quite a lot of meat without much hassle on part of the butcher(I could be wrong, feel free to correct).

Assuming they aren't much different from earth's land slugs, aside from their size and an increase in overall safety to consume due to them being raised by slug ranchers specifically for consumption, **can the flesh of a giant slug, which grows to the size of an adult micro pig, be cut and prepared as a steak?**

Comment: Ask the french or south italians how they cook slugs and snails

Comment: L'escargot aren't very steaklike, but they're tasty. I think the answer is 'no, if you care about texture, yes, if you don't'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dune referenced something like this, though it went the extra mile and didn't just have slugs the size of pigs, but made a slimy meaty chimera. Sligpork.

Anyway. Slugs are molluscs who kinda lost their shell along the way. Squid are molluscs who kinda lost their shell along the way. Seems like a reasonable starting point.

[Calamari steaks](https://www.delightedcooking.com/what-are-calamari-steaks.htm) are a thing:

> Calamari steaks are large, flat pieces of squid meat. These pieces of meat often come from large squids, particularly Humboldt squids, and they may be either fresh or frozen. Since squid is a tough and rubbery meat, calamari steaks should be tenderized before cooking. They can be cooked quickly, on a stove, or slowly, in the oven.

Snails are also a thing that people cook and eat, though they tend to be pretty tough and rubbery too and apparently require a bit of boiling to soften up.

Slugs tend to be quite a bit more slimy than snails, because due to the lack of shell they have to rely more on their slime for protection. This probably means that any cut of your giant slug is probably made *after* boiling and cleaning, otherwise there will be an unpleasant residue on the meat that you almost certainly don't want to eat.

So, you probably won't get steaks that are quite like mammal meat, but you may be able to get something a bit like a slice of big cephalopod. Obviously there's no real world information to draw upon, but I wonder if with a bit of clever [brining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brining) or [pickling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickling) with the right mix of salt and vinegar and a bit of manual scrubbing you might be able to simultaeously remove the slime and cure the meat... more like ham than pork or beef steak, and perhaps more like a [ceviche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceviche) or [escabeche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escabeche) than either. There's also apparently an arabic or persian precusor to those preparation methods, but I can't find a reference to it offhand.

Anyway, you then have a second cooking process before eating it. This might have to be boiling, but you could get away with roasting or frying if it isn't too tough, or marinading softens it enough, or you tenderised it well.

You might also find that farmed giant slugs have quite different "meat" to wild cephalopods, in the same way that modern domesticated mammals produce more and fattier meat than their wild relatives. There's more than enough wiggle room here to get the sort of texture you want, I'd say.

Comment: To be honest, if U.S. football fans are any indication, if the diameter of the cut is reasonably close and the critter can be cut into 1" thick slices, you betcha. Grill it, sauce it, wolf it down, cheer for the team, deal with gastroenteritis later. O'course, maybe the closest Real Life example is beef liver....